# Raspberry Pi 4 и подключение датчика движения

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

[image: Raspberry Pi 4]
Заранее скажу, что я не гуру в теме данной электроники, поэтому если можно, то распишите ответ простым языком.

[image: Код]

Проблема заключается в том, что при движении объекта, датчик передаёт мне по ssh информацию на компьютер, есть ли движение. И когда я чем-то занят, я не всегда смотрю на cmd и получается, так что я не замечаю движение. Я сижу и думаю, как можно передавать звук на ПК, когда срабатывает датчик?

Заранее спасибо )

Comment: ну и как вопрос соотносится с текстом?

Comment: Передавайте те же сообщения что и сейчас. А на компьютере, где есть устройство для вывода звука пишите другую программу, которая принимает эти данные от устройства и создает звук.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, очень большая просьба: **никогда** не вставляйте в вопрос скриншоты! Ну разве что, вопрос конкретно рисовании на экране.

Если бы Вы вставили в вопрос **текст** программы (или его часть), я бы подкорректировал его и вставил в ответ. А так - глазами считывать Ваш скриншот и самому вписывать его в ответ - мне совсем не хочется. Поэтому ограничусь советами:

1. Вызовы *setmode()* совсем не нужно делать в цикле. Более того, их даже нужно вынести из цикла.
2. Соответственно, в конце работы программы нужно сказать ОС, что Вы прекращаете работу с этими пинами: GPIO.cleanup(). Иначе будут проблемы с последующим запуском этой или других програм, использующих RPi.GPIO.
3. Что бы "попискивать" малинкой можно использовать модули типа KY-006 (https://arduinomodules.info/ky-006-passive-buzzer-module/)

Пользоваться этой пищалкой можно как-то так:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 
#The output pin
GPIO_PIN = 21
GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

pwm = GPIO.PWM(GPIO_PIN, 500)
pwm.start(50)
# The program will wait for the input of a new frequency.

try:
    while(True):
        print "—————————————-"
        print "Current frequency: %d" % 500
        Frequency = input("Please input a new frequency (50-5000):")
        pwm.ChangeFrequency(Frequency)
         
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Окей, спасибо за ответ.